# Why Laravel Eloquent wasChanged and getChanges functions shows wrong updated fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use `wasChanged` and `getChanges` functions to determine updated fields of `updateOrCreate` function.

Previously it was working great but after adding a boolean field to updateOrCreate, `wasChanged` returns `true` and `getChanges` returns the field as updated when it's not changed.

I tried to cast value to boolean but nothing resolved.

What might be the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of what you added and the code that is using `wasChanged` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the value that you pass is boolean data type and I just use `wasRecentlyCreated` function. Below is one of my example code.

```php
    $boolean_req_ext= htmlentities($request->form_req_ext)==='true'?true:false;

     $dataArray= [
            'status'=> $status,
            'req_extension'=>$boolean_req_ext,
        ];

    $originalObsExt = ObservationExt::find($id)->getOriginal();

    $data = ObservationExt::updateOrCreate($dataArray);
    //https://medium.com/@JinoAntony/10-hidden-laravel-eloquent-features-you-may-not-know-efc8ccc58d9e
    //https://freek.dev/951-use-the-wasrecentlycreated-model-attribute-to-check-if-your-model-was-created-or-found
    if (!$data->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $changes = $data->getChanges();

            $obsExtTrailArr = array(
                'status'=>isset($changes["status"])?$originalObsExt["status"]:null,
                'req_extension'=>isset($changes["req_extension"])?$originalObsExt["req_extension"]:null,
               );

       
            $createTrail = ObservationExtTrail::create(
                    $obsExtTrailArr 
                );
    }
```